# remove:function line while Printing Array in Console - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using Chrome.
I've got a multidimensional array 'stories'

I'm printing 'stories' using `console.log(stories);`

Console log shows me all 24 elements of 'stories' in the console, but the first line of the console expansion arrow shows `[remove:function]`

[image]

When I try to print out to the console an individual array element using `console.log(stories[2]);`, it doesn't work. The console prints out `undefined`.

So, printing all array elements works just fine, but printing out an individual element doesn't.

Any idea what may be happening?

My end goal is to sort this array, and it is not working right now, and I am thinking that these issues are related.

Any advice greatly appreciated! thanks!

Further info:
I'm making an array and then passing elements into the array. each element is a sharepoint list item.

```
  var stories = new Array();
  getMyGPShareListData(".../ListProxy.html?listname=NewsArticles&odata=%24top%3D3%26%24orderby%3DArticleDate%20desc", { success: successGPNowData, error: errorGPNowData }); 
   function successGPNowData(data) {
    //Handle SharePoint REST List Items
    if (data.d) {
        iReturns = iReturns + 1;
        //Determine data results to pass to top nav
        jQuery.each(data.d, function (n, item) {
          item.ArticleDate = item.ArticleDate.substr(6).replace(")/","");
          stories.push(item);
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you make `stories`? Maybe `stories` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @halcyon thanks ive added further info

Comment: You're seeing `[remove:function]` because you are setting `Array.prototype.remove` somewhere.

Comment: Ok, make sure you do `console.log(stories[2]);` inside `successGPNowData()`. I'm guessing there is an asynchronous call involved (like AJAX). You should get a result then. Also, the object looks like it might be serializable so you can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(stories));` to inspect it as well.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Afair, prototype properties (even if enumerable) are not displayed there?

Comment: @Bergi Try this: `Array.prototype.remove = function () {}; console.log([]);` It does print `remove` for me (no `__proto__`). I think this might have recently changed in Chrome.

Comment: Have found any solution for this? I'm having the same issue, look's like an external library is adding that function in the prototype but I can't figure out remove the method from there... the before assignation doesnt work